# Is it possible to skip the AssemblyInitialize attribute for special tests?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mstest

I have two tests: `BooUnitTest` and `BooIntegrationTest`.

Within the same testing project I'm holding a method with the `AssemblyInitialize` attribute decorator:

`AssemblyTestsHandler.cs`

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

[TestClass]
public class AssemblyTestsHandler
{
    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public static async Task Bootstrap()
    {
        //Do complex stuff...
    }
}
```

Is it possible to make the Bootstrap method that works only for `BooIntegrationTest` and not for `FooUnitTest`?

For example

`FooTests.cs`:

```
[TestClass]
public class FooTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task FooUnitTest()
    {
        //Skip Bootstrap()!!
    }
}
```

`BooTests.cs`

```
[TestClass]
public class BooTests
{    
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task BooIntegrationTest()
    {
        //Do Not Skip Bootstrap()!!
    }
}
```

Here is the project structure:

```
TestingProject

-AssemblyTestsHandler.cs

-BooTests.cs

-FooTests.cs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. `AssemblyInitialize` will be called once per assembly and it will be called before all other methods ([AssemblyInitializeAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ms245278(v=vs.90))):

> The method marked with this attribute will be run before methods
> marked with the ClassInitializeAttribute, TestInitializeAttribute, and
> TestMethodAttribute attributes. Only one method in an assembly may be
> decorated with this attribute.

Actually unit tests should be executed in random order:

1. FooUnitTest1
2. BooIntegrationTest2
3. FooUnitTest2
4. BooIntegrationTest1

in this case any static initialization will affect all other unit-tests.

I think, there are two possibilities:

1. You can use `TestInitialize` and `TestCleanup` attributes for `FooTests`. But this will affect performance
2. You can use [`ClassInitialize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ms245248(v=vs.90)) for `BooTests`, but in this case, you have to trigger integration tests separately from unit tests. Integration- and unit tests can be distinguished by `TestCathegory` attribute.

Comment: So it looks like I should create a different solution